# Purpose of Install-ADServiceAccount

Tags: powershell, active-directory, account

I create grouped managed service account gMSA by running command `New-ADServiceAccount` and I specify `-PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword`. At the very moment of creation I am able to use gMSA on computer which is specified as `-PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword`.

What is the purpose of `Install-ADServiceAccount`? I have found many blogs where people say to run it but nobody explains reason why to do it.

I am not doing it and everything works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Install-ADServiceAccount` is used for installing/linking an MSA to the computer so it's available to be used. This is needed because MSA have a one-to-one relationship with a computer. It does not apply to gMSA which can be shared. gMSA only require you to set the permissions using `New-/Set-ADServiceAccount`

How to use gMSA: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj128431.aspx

Comment: Thanks.Sounds very reasonable.